# "axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'" but axios.post still is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: javascript, axios

I set axios common header Content-Type = application/json by below code:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

But when I tried to use `axios.post('apiurl', json)`, browser Content-Type still is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]

I tried to use `axios.post('Get_Office_PO_NO_Data', json, { headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } })` and axios can request `application/json content type`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults), you want `post`, not `common`:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^
```

Which makes sense; other request types (`GET`, `DELETE`, etc.) don't have any request body to apply the content type to. (`PUT` and `PATCH` do, but I guess they figured it was unlikely you'd want to set the same default content type for `POST` and `PUT`, or it was just the whim of the developer.)

(Alternatively you might consider [creating an instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults) with your defaults via `axios.create`, and then using the instance. Changing global defaults always makes me a bit uneasy. :-) )